# Download pdf in headless chrome and selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

**Script.py**

```
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF 
Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
           "download.default_directory": source_dir, 
"download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"}
ChromeOptions.add_argument('--headless')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--test-type')
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
a835file = 
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/a')
a835file.click()
```

### Issue

The script runs fine and i can see the file is found but it doesn't download it.

Comment: I used to achieve this in java using robot class by passing ctrl+s and using the same we can pass download directory as well.

Comment: but as the script runs headless i dont think ctrl+s would work.

Comment: Is it a must requirement to download on click or you can use urllib to fetch the source of pdf?

Comment: this is how i am downloading : profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
               "download.default_directory": source_dir, "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"}. but on running headless this download doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

This issue is currently being looked at on [GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5159) (contains a possible solution too).

This is actually seen as a feature and its functionality is intended. There is a work around in Java on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471151/chromium-chrome-headless-file-download-not-working/42583255#42583255) and a python version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium).

Comment: i was trying to find a resource in python..

Comment: @DimpleMathew have edited the response to include python workaround

Comment: yea... i did do thru that.. but it dint work for me

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can you update your question with what you have tried?